# Doesn't show the video for some reason

Tags: python, html, django

I have a model of where the user can choose the title of their video and can upload the video but for some reason when I try to display the video in the html and I visit that page it does a GET request on the file but the file doesn't include .mp4 on the end so it doesn't work.

Tried a few things but I can't remember what exactly since it was a few days ago and none of them worked.

**My models.py:**

```
# Create your models here.
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    video_file = models.FileField(name="Upload a mp4 file",
                                  upload_to=f"uploadvideos/video",
                                  validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['mp4'])],
                                  blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**My views.py:**

```
def movie(request, movie_id):
    video = get_object_or_404(Video, title=movie_id)
    context = {'video': video}
    return render(request, template_name=f'uploadvideos/movie.html', context=context)
```

**My html template:**

```
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="movietitle">{{ movie }}</h1>
    <div class="videoDetails">
        <video width="700" height="430" controls>
            <source src="{{ idk what to put here }}" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it will be like this:

```
{% for i in video %}
     <source src="{{ i.video_file.url }}" type="video/mp4">
{% endfor %}
```